# Wordpress Send email before specified time for each user

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I need to send an email (a type of reminder) to a user 7 days, 3 days and 1 day before a specific date that the user has chosen during his signup/registration in wordpress.

I have created the date field using ACF and I thought using cronjob to try and send but I am not able to send it based on the parameters above.

So can anyone suggest me maybe a hook, a solution or a plugin that might do this?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: Can you show code of what you are trying?

Comment: Hi David,
Yes, I was trying this: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/acf-date-field-email-reminder/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do that specific case you need but I think you have to use wp_cron.
Take a look at [wp_cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) and [wp_schedule_single_event](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event). Be careful of overusing wp_cron. If you have to send the email to multiple users at the same time you should create only one cron and not 1000. If you provide some further informations what you exactly do we can maybe help more specific.

Best,
Patrick